# Why isn't the netflix app doing UHD output on my PC?

Tags: display, netflix

We recently upgraded our netflix plan to allow for UHD video. Unfortunately I've not been able to get this to work on my PC so far

From what I looked up, these seem to be the requirements

> An Intel 7th Gen or newer CPU or an AMD Ryzen CPU
> A Radeon RX 400 or newer or Nvidia with these specs (if you have a dedicated GPU)
> A 60Hz+ 4K display with HDCP 2.2 support
> 25 Mbps or higher download speed

- I have a  Nvidia 3080 - which is a supported GPU. amd a 9th generation core i9, so I'm handily exceeding requirements.
- I'm using the 'native' netflix app
- I have the HEVC drivers set up, and have confirmed that MPC-BE (which needs these drivers installed to run HEVC) works. I'm running the "HEVC extentions from device manufacturer" which I downloaded before the loophole was closed, and its identical to the paid one. I've nearly identical software but not hardware on another PC and its able to play Netflix at 4k so I'm fairly certain its not a hardware issue

As far as I can tell, I'm meeting or exceeding the requirements needed, and I see no UHD content, and the [test patterns](https://www.netflix.com/title/80018499) (netflix subscription needed) tell me its running at 1080p

- I tested with a dual monitor set up (with both monitors compatible with HDCP). My third monitor does not at the moment so I took it out of the equation for testing. I unplugged that monitor, rebooted then started netflix, so its not that the application picked it up at reboot time.

The P270s are 4k 60 monitors, connected over Display port, and work fine at 4k.

I've also tried a single monitor over HDMI

[image]

Interestingly nvidia says it supported and the [cyberlink tool for checking for BD compliance](https://www.cyberlink.com/stat/bd-support/enu/index.jsp) (that's woefully outdated and links to a broken link when you try to download it) says it is not.

[image]

We suspect the [chrome EME checker](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/hdcp-detection/) is giving HDCP 1.0 supported as the highest supported version no matter what - so I don't trust it. I ran tests on another system and it *does* do UHD on a different display  *and* it fails past HDCP 1.0 on that test so its incorrect

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit of testing - and worked out a few things.

Nearly no publicly available application will tell you if HDCP support is at the right level for this.

My monitor *does not* support HCDP 2.2 from what I can tell.
From what I can tell - there's a minimum version of DP 1.4a (mine does 1.2 I think) for HDCP 2.2 support and I can't really find any minimum version for HDCP when I google. My monitor *does* support HDMI 2.0

In my case - since replacing my monitor is a little much for 'testing' - I ended up picking up a "EDID Emulator" based on some online advice, and its a device that 'feeds' the PC either a predefined EDID persona or one you can clone off a working machine. Mine had a bunch of dip switches, and I set mine to emulate the same monitor resolution and frequency I have.

[image]

Its this unit, and its fairly generic. It needs a USB  port for power and connects to both your monitor and PC.

With it plugged in between my monitor and computer - things get interesting

[image]

It passes the cyberlink test (but that dosen't tell me *which* monitor passed), but the netflix test pattern fails to run at 4k.

When other monitors are unplugged (One's known non HDCP compliant, the other is identical to the monitor I am testing on) from power, the netflix pattern *does* run. I'm guessing the cyberlink BD tester detects *one* monitor is HDCP compliant and netflix detects the other ones are *not*.(Netflix's behaviour is correct but *annoying*),

Basically - I'd guess my monitor just doesn't support it, and if I do want to watch entirely legally obtained movies off a streaming service, this is the requisite amount of faffing around needed.

Answer (score 1):

CyberLink is telling you in the graphic you pasted at the top.

> Graphics Card Driver "No"

There are two drivers that NVIDIA ships,

- GRD - Game Ready
- SD - Studio

Entirely consistent with NVIDIA everywhere else, this is insane so brace for it: [only the **Studio driver supports HDCP 2.2**](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4583/%7E/4k-uhd-netflix-content-on-nvidia-gpus). You'll need [to download the Studio driver](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx), or if you got the cash buy an ATI card!

---

Onto some other things though,

- You're using Windows: you never need an EDID emulator and in fact you should never trust one with dip switches. You can edit the EDID with AW EDID (or any hex editor), and do far more (like check what it contains and make the EDID report that DP 1.4a is supported! [Which is sometimes required elsewhere.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/457124/76955) After you have edited the EDID blob, you can [store the edited blob on Windows as an overwrite by following these steps from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/overriding-monitor-edids#updating-an-edid).
- Your monitor almost surely supports HDCP 2.2. But to test it cheaply plug the a Netflix device right up into it, like a ChromeCast, or Amazon Fire stick. You said the monitor is a "P270", but I don't see that online. But HDCP 2.2 is like 10 years old.
- If all that fails, you can always [buy an HD Fury device and ignore HDCP entirely forever,](https://www.amazon.com/stores/page/5E01EB84-ED67-4EA6-8793-FF2131AA1DAD) since it's a failed system and the Dark Side lost their lawsuit against them.

Comment: Prism  (the company that makes the monitor) a bit weird - they're a singapore only brand, that badge engineers other companies. Though now that you mention it - testing the monitor in isolation with another system that I think *does* do netflix in 4k would determine if its the monitor . The HD Fury, and the dodgy aliexpress box do the same thing.  I *also* suspect the cyberlink tool's wrong - its hugely outdated and not supported. It does reflect though that this is a hugely frustrating mess. I *might* also be rebuilding the machine in future so testing the studio drivers might be an option

Comment: But I don't quite see where it says the gameready driver won't do HDCP 2.2 on your link, *and* it worked with the emulator box in between the monitor and PC so I'm kinda curious why you would think so. If its sending a stream of I'm watching to china, I don't really care, and it was a relatively cheap way to remove one variable. Not needing the box would be nice tho, or finding out it *is* supported

Comment: And while I'm ranting, what would be really nice if a company that charged you extra for 4k support would just go "Ok, you can't run 4k because (thing)" outright. Then we wouldn't be faffing around with mysterious black boxes, software that I need to hut down off majorgeeks, Tomato Sacrifices and other mysterious things.

Comment: @JourneymanGeekOnStrike I could be wrong on my reading. they say "NVIDIA Driver" instead of "GeForce Driver". It's just an assumption. Your cable also needs to be HDCP/HDMI 2.0 and many of them are not. If in doubt, try the Amazon basics one, those are some of the best cables you can buy. But definitely ditch the emulator, as that's a potential source of problems regardless. Use AW EDID and override for less voodoo.

Comment: The reason why you don't want the emulator is because you don't know what the EDID your monitor is sending. For example, let's say your monitor supports 160hz update, and the EDID made for wide applicability only reports that the monitor supports 90hz update. You may be losing 70hz because your graphics card won't actually know your screen supports 160hz. But it's not just this. EDID sends back all kinds of crap information that you really don't want emulated blindly.

Comment: The emulator is the 'one' thing that worked on 'this' setup. I literally bought it to test - and it does help me determine the problem was with the PC and nowhere else. I know the monitor does 4k60 - and I matched the settings as closely as possible. It *is* a wierd chinese piece of junk of all sorts of dodgyness, but in this case I have it dialed in for use on the monitors I have. Besides, as long as I convince the netflix app that its supported, and the video output looks good, I'm not too fussed if its lying to my PC